# After I search in Explorer, how can I open a sub-folder with full path, not as a search folder?

Tags: windows-explorer

I search for `bar`, and get this:

[image]

How can I open the `baz` subfolder in a way that will make Explorer show the full path? Meaning, I want this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Comment: After the search is completed, press Ctrl+L.

Comment: Just double-click the folder to display it fully.

Answer (score 0):

You could always hold shift + right click on the folder, then copy as path.

Comment: This looks like the first step in a good answer.  Please post the entire answer.